# Python lxml printing issue

Tags: python, xml, for-loop, printing, lxml

I'm working with the Lxml library. I'm having some issues printing the information the way I want.

Any idea how I can turn this:

```
Lista vídeo: PV1
Lista vídeo: PV2
   Link:http://i.imgur.com/BOApo7g.jpg
   Link:http://i3.ytimg.com/vi/uMK0prafzw0/hqdefault.jpg
```

Into this:

```
 Lista vídeo: PV1
    Link:http://i.imgur.com/BOApo7g.jpg
 Lista vídeo: PV2 
    Link:http://i3.ytimg.com/vi/uMK0prafzw0/hqdefault.jpg
```

This is my Python 3.4.3 code:

```
    import lxml.etree as ElementTree

treeDoc = ElementTree.parse("XMLTube.xml")
listas = treeDoc.xpath("//lista")


def printListasVideos(treeDoc):
    printListaVideo("link")


def printListaVideo(listaVideoElem):
        for lista in listas:
            print("Lista vídeo: " + lista.get("id"))

        if listaVideoElem == "link":
            links = treeDoc.xpath("//thumbnail")
            for link in links:
                print("  " + "Link:" + link.get("link"))
```

XML code:
(it's in portuguese but I don't think that matters)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE xml_tube SYSTEM "C:\Users\Asus\Desktop\LEIM\tps\tp2\Lista Geral de Utilizadores\xml__tube.dtd">

<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="Videos.xsl"?>

<xml_tube>
    <utilizadores>
        <utilizador username="Guicky" password="futurama96">
            <nome>Guilherme Luís</nome>
            <birthday>1996-11-28</birthday>
            <foto href="http://i.imgur.com/fKVoJAA.jpg"/>
        </utilizador>
        <utilizador username="Daisy" password="woofwoof11">
            <nome>Daisy Luís</nome>
            <birthday>2011-04-04</birthday>
            <foto href="http://i.imgur.com/EgkXou1.jpg"/>
        </utilizador>
        <utilizador username="Anabela65" password="crumble65">
            <nome>Anabela Ribeiro</nome>
            <birthday>1965-04-02</birthday>
            <foto href="http://i.imgur.com/ccIzEv6.jpg"/>
        </utilizador>
        <utilizador username="Izzie" password="lagartixa">
            <nome>Isadora Luís</nome>
            <birthday>1988-06-27</birthday>
            <foto href="http://i.imgur.com/AttHDR1.jpg"/>
        </utilizador>
    </utilizadores>
    <videos_pub>
        <video id="Vid1" publisher="Daisy" duracao="3:37" data="2016-02-29">
            <título> Baha Men - Who let the dogs out?</título>
            <thumb>http://i3.ytimg.com/vi/Qkuu0Lwb5EM/hqdefault.jpg</thumb>
            <descrição>My favorite song, lol.</descrição>
            <hyperlink>https://www.youtube.com/embed/He82NBjJqf8</hyperlink>
            <qualidade pixelization="1080p"/>
            <qualidade pixelization="480p"/>
            <likes liked="Guicky"/>
        </video>
        <video id="Vid2" publisher="Guicky" duracao="4:01" data="2016-02-29">
            <título>Desiigner - Timmy Turner</título>
            <thumb>http://i3.ytimg.com/vi/JzmRt2VgKYQ/hqdefault.jpg</thumb>
            <descrição>Timmy Timmy Timmy Turner.</descrição>
            <hyperlink>https://www.youtube.com/embed/ProbPpO_8oo</hyperlink>
            <qualidade pixelization="720p"/>
            <qualidade pixelization="1080p"/>
            <likes liked="Anabela65"/>
            <likes liked="Daisy"/>
            <related>
                <link id="Vid3"/>
                <link id="Vid4"/>
            </related>
        </video>
        <video id="Vid3" publisher="Guicky" duracao="3:47" data="2016-02-29">
            <título>Fat Joe - I'm all the way up</título>
            <thumb>http://i3.ytimg.com/vi/y2ak_oBeC-I/hqdefault.jpg</thumb>
            <descrição>Nothing can stop me, I'm all the way up.</descrição>
            <hyperlink>https://www.youtube.com/embed/y2ak_oBeC-I</hyperlink>
            <qualidade pixelization="480p"/>
            <qualidade pixelization="720p"/>
            <likes liked="Guicky"/>
            <likes liked="Daisy"/>
            <likes liked="Anabela65"/>
            <likes liked="Izzie"/>
            <related>
                <link id="Vid2"/>
            </related>
        </video>
        <video id="Vid4" publisher="Anabela65" duracao="3:21" data="2016-02-29">
            <título>Putzgrilla - Sentadinha</título>
            <thumb>http://i3.ytimg.com/vi/QC4JbIvIhdI/hqdefault.jpg</thumb>
            <descrição>Dá uma sentadinha.</descrição>
            <hyperlink>https://www.youtube.com/embed/QC4JbIvIhdI</hyperlink>
            <qualidade pixelization="720p"/>
            <likes liked="Guicky"/>
            <likes liked="Daisy"/>
            <related>
                <link id="Vid2"/>
            </related>
        </video>
        <video data="2017-01-13" duracao="02:16" id="Vid5" publisher="Izzie">
            <título>Yann Tiersen - La Valse d'Amelie</título>
            <thumb>http://i3.ytimg.com/vi/uzurqBnALkw/hqdefault.jpg</thumb>
            <descrição>A minha música preferida.</descrição>
            <hyperlink>https://www.youtube.com/embed/uzurqBnALkw</hyperlink>
            <qualidade pixelization="720p"/>
            <likes liked="Guicky"/>
            <likes liked="Anabela65"/>
        </video>
    </videos_pub>
    <playlist>
        <lista owner="Guicky" dataIns="2016-10-24" id="PV1">
            <titulo>BEST MUSIC.</titulo>
            <descricao>Compilation of my favourite music videos.</descricao>
            <gostosL gostouL="Guicky"/>
            <links_vid vid="Vid2"/>
            <links_vid vid="Vid3"/>
            <administradores>
                <admin ref="Guicky"/>
                <admin ref="Daisy"/>
            </administradores>
            <editores>
                <editor ref="Guicky"/>
            </editores>
            <subscritores>
                <subs ref="Daisy"/>
                <subs ref="Anabela65"/>
            </subscritores>
            <thumbnail link="http://i.imgur.com/BOApo7g.jpg"/>
        </lista>
        <lista owner="Anabela65" dataIns="2016-02-29" id="PV2">
            <titulo>Sentadinha!</titulo>
            <descricao>Siting lesson's with Guicky's mom!</descricao>
            <links_vid vid="Vid4"/>
            <administradores>
                <admin ref="Anabela65"/>
                <admin ref="Guicky"/>
            </administradores>
            <editores>
                <editor ref="Anabela65"/>
            </editores>
            <subscritores>
                <subs ref="Guicky"/>
                <subs ref="Daisy"/>
            </subscritores>
            <thumbnail link="http://i3.ytimg.com/vi/uMK0prafzw0/hqdefault.jpg"/>
        </lista>
    </playlist>
    <comentarios>
        <comentario id="C1" refV="Vid1" user="Guicky" data="2016-10-23">
            <text>AHAHAHAHA, bom vídeo.</text>
            <gosto gostou="Daisy"/>
            <respostas>
                <texto autor="Daisy">Grande clássico!</texto>
            </respostas>
        </comentario>
        <comentario id="C2" refL="Vid2" user="Anabela65" data="2016-10-22">
            <text>Timmy timmy timmy turner...</text>
            <gosto gostou="Guicky"/>
            <gosto gostou="Daisy"/>
            <respostas>
                <texto autor="Guicky">U know it.</texto>
                <resposta autor="Daisy">LOL!</resposta>
            </respostas>
        </comentario>
    </comentarios>
</xml_tube>
```

Comment: Please provide the sample data to understand the xml structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me know if this works for you. Note that I made few changes to your base code

```
import lxml.etree as ElementTree

def printListasVideos():
    treeDoc = ElementTree.parse("inv1.xml")
    listas = treeDoc.xpath("//lista")
    for lista in listas:
        printListaVideo(lista)

def printListaVideo(listAElement):
    print("Lista vídeo: " + listAElement.get("id"))
    links = listAElement.findall(".//thumbnail")
    for link in links:
        print link.get('link')   

printListasVideos()
```

Output

```
Lista vídeo: PV1
http://i.imgur.com/BOApo7g.jpg
Lista vídeo: PV2
http://i3.ytimg.com/vi/uMK0prafzw0/hqdefault.jpg
```

Comment: It does, thank you a lot. Can you just tell how does `findall` works? Thanks!

Comment: http://infohost.nmt.edu/~shipman/soft/pylxml/web/Element-findall.html -findall returns the complete list of elements matching the match xpath